# Change max/min values of range slider

Tags: onsen-ui

I need to change the max and min values of the range sliders in onsen-ui. By default, it appears to be from 0 to 100 (min to max). Is there any way to edit these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `min` and `max` attributes in `<input>` tag.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script>
  ons.bootstrap();
</script>
    <ons-page ng-init="slider=30">

      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">
          Ranges
        </div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <ons-icon icon="fa-volume-down" class="lower"></ons-icon>
      <input type="range" min="20" max="60" class="range" ng-model="slider">
      <ons-icon icon="fa-volume-up"></ons-icon>
      <p>{{slider}}</p>
    </ons-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**. Ons range has value from 0 to 100. You can use value attribute to set default value to range. So, if you wished to change the range value, you could do it by ng-model doing some mathematical treatise. For example I have set range min=10 and max=300 and the scaling factor=10 in the example below:

```
<script>
  ons.bootstrap();
</script>
    <ons-page>
Range in meters: <ons-range value="10" ng-model="range"></ons-range> 
{{(((range*10)>=10&&(range*10)<=300)&&range*10+'meters')||(....)}}

    </ons-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the ONSEN ons-range min / max attributes

`<ons-range min="0" max="10"  value="5" id="myrange"></ons-range>`

You can also change the min/max dynamically in a script

```
var slider =  document.getElementById("myrange");
slider.setAttribute('step', 1);
slider.setAttribute('value', 0);
slider.setAttribute('min', 0);
slider.setAttribute('max', 50);
```